# Well-ordering on natural numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\omega=\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$. We say that $\omega$ is a well-ordered set. But I can't understand why. By the definition of well-ordering, there should be no infinite descending chain, but if I start from infinity, how can I reach 0 in finite descents? Or is this not allowed? Is this nonsensical to choose infinity? Then what about $\omega+1$? Is this set well-ordered? How can I reach to $0$ from $\omega$?

Comment: This wikipedia article might help you: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order

Comment: @Omar I have read it. But couldn't get my doubt cleared from it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every descending chain in $\omega$ has to start somewhere - specifically, it must start with a finite value $n$. One cannot "start from infinity" within $\omega$ since every element of $\omega$ is finite.

$\omega + 1$ is well-ordered in the obvious way. Suppose we have a descending chain beginning with $\omega$. Then the next element in the chain must be some $n < \omega$: that is, some finite $n$. After that point, it's clear there can only be finitely many steps until reaching zero.

Comment: So we can not land into the floating infinities in between? So $\omega$ is like some island in the infinite sea surrounding us? And we can do our usual math only on these islands, not in the sea?

Comment: There are no infinities in between.  Although there are infinitely many natural numbers, no specific natural number is infinite.  So, a specific number before $\omega$ will be finite.

Comment: @badjohn thanks.

Comment: @user180446 $\omega+1$ is not "a larger infinity", it's just a countable set (so same size as $\omega$!) with a slightly different well-order.